# Who comes and what will happen in Edom Bozrah?

Tags: commentaries, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Looking at [Isaiah 63:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.63.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> Who is this coming from Edom? In crimsoned garments from Bozrah.
> Who is this, majestic in attire, pressing forward in His great might?
> “It is I, who contend victoriously, powerful to give triumph.”

Who will come and do what?
What is this verse talking about? What will happen?

It seems this verse relates to other verses about Teman, Edom etc.

Can anyone tell me the bigger story?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a digest of commentaries from R Adin Steinsaltz and artscroll translations of Tanakh.

Context is that the redemption of Israel will be accompanied by vengeance upon Israel's enemies which the prophet describes in the vivid form of a figure arriving from Edom with blood-stained garments.

The chapter describes the retribution Edom will suffer for its ruthless destruction of the Second Temple and persecution of Israel through the current exile. In the prophetic vision, the onlooker wonders at the fate of Edom until God himself, as it were, declares that indeed it is He Himself who punishes Edom and delivers Israel. In the metaphor, God appears as a human avenger wreaking destruction on his enemies.

Commentators debate whether the question is posed by Israel (Rashi), an anonymous observer (Radak) or the prophet's own theoretical question (Abarbanel).

According to Radak, Bozrah is a prominent Edomite city (see [34:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.34.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). There are other views (e.g., a metaphor for any place adopting the customs of Edom or a Moabite city).

See also [Makot 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.12a.4?lang=bi)

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe specifically pointed out the Iraqi city of Basra with this section of Isaiah and discussed it in the context of the coming of King Moshiach. As I recall, he also pointed out that this particular prophecy  was a multi-part prophecy that would span several different times periods related to the "Days of Moshiach". He also emphasized that the graphic language should not be taken literally, but as allegorical language. He repeated this point many times in connection with the language found in Yalkut Shimoni on Isaiah.

Comment: Is this verse related to other verses about Edom (or Edomite regions such as Teman, Selah (Petra?) and Seïr?  If so, which ones?